# Pivot multiple columns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to convert column to rows. I am beginner to PIVOT. Tried below code but error is coming as *'Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.
The incorrect value "Tot_GPS_Cnt" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.'*

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl_Res1 
( 
  CallDate DATETIME, 
  Tot_GPS_Cnt INT, 
  Tot_GND_Cnt INT,  
  Per_Ratio NUMERIC(10,2) 
)

INSERT INTO #tbl_Res1 
SELECT '2015-04-24 00:00:00.000','40','26','65.00' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-04-25 00:00:00.000','22','14','63.64' UNION ALL 
SELECT'2015-04-26 00:00:00.000','27','21','77.78' UNION ALL
SELECT'2015-04-27 00:00:00.000','41','23','56.10'
```

Source Table

[image]

Desired Output

[image]

I have tried with below query bu failing. Please help. Thanks in advance

```
SELECT CallDate=col, Tot_GPS_Cnt, Tot_GND_Cnt, Per_Ratio
FROM 
( select CallDate, col, value from #tbl_Res1
  cross apply 
  ( 
    SELECT 'Tot_GPS_Cnt',cast(Tot_GPS_Cnt as varchar(10)) UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Tot_GND_Cnt', cast(Tot_GND_Cnt as varchar(10)) UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Per_Ratio', cast(Per_Ratio as varchar(10))
  ) c (col,value)
) d 
PIVOT
(
max(value) for CallDate in ([Tot_GPS_Cnt], [Tot_GND_Cnt], [Per_Ratio])
) as piv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for [**PIVOT**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is:

```
PIVOT
(    
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)    
    FOR    
    [<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]

    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],

    ... [last pivoted column])

) AS <alias for the pivot table>
```

Hence, you have to place *date values* not `[Tot_GPS_Cnt], [Tot_GND_Cnt], [Per_Ratio]` in place of pivoted columns:

```
SELECT CallDate=col, [2015-04-24], [2015-04-25], [2015-04-26], [2015-04-27]
FROM 
( select CallDate, col, value from #tbl_Res1
  cross apply 
  ( 
    SELECT 'Tot_GPS_Cnt',cast(Tot_GPS_Cnt as varchar(10)) UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Tot_GND_Cnt', cast(Tot_GND_Cnt as varchar(10)) UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Per_Ratio', cast(Per_Ratio as varchar(10))
  ) c (col,value)
) d 
PIVOT
(
max(value) for CallDate in ([2015-04-24], [2015-04-25], [2015-04-26], [2015-04-27])
) as piv
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. Can we make this dynamic because table data used to change/grow.

Comment: @RonakVyas Well, that is a different question. You may have a look at *dynamic pivot*. You will find plenty of examples here in SO.

Comment: Ok sure. Thank you very much. I will work on this to make dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Giorgos Betsos. I just made dynamic solution. Just wanted to share with all.

```
DECLARE @coldata VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @coldata = COALESCE(@coldata + '], [', '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),calldate,110) 
FROM #tbl_Res1;
SELECT @coldata = '[' + @coldata +']';
SELECT @coldata;


SET @sql = 'SELECT CallDate=col, ' + @coldata + '
  FROM 
  ( SELECT CallDate, col, value FROM #tbl_Res1
    cross apply 
    ( 
      SELECT ''Tot_GPS_Cnt'', CAST(Tot_GPS_Cnt as VARCHAR(10)) UNION ALL
      SELECT ''Tot_GND_Cnt'', CAST(Tot_GND_Cnt as VARCHAR(10)) UNION ALL
      SELECT ''Per_Ratio'', CAST(Per_Ratio as VARCHAR(10))
    ) c (col,value)
  ) d 
  PIVOT
  (
    MAX(value) FOR CallDate IN (' + @coldata + ')
  ) as piv'

  SELECT @sql;

  EXECUTE (@SQL);
```